# React - How to route parent div from child div

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm attempting to route the main app from a selection in one of its children's children's components. My project is structured like this:

```
<Main>
    <titlebar>
    <Router>
        <Link to={"/home}>Home</Link>
        <Link to={"/search}>Search</Link>
        ...
    </Router>

    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}
        <Route exact path="/search" component={Search} />
    <Switch>
    <footer>
</Main>

<Home>
    <Messages and stuff>
    ...
    <List />
    ...
<Home>

<List>
    list.map => (
        <button?>View</button>
        <thing.id>
        ...
    )
</List>

<View>
    ...info about thing ...
</View>
```

My goal is to be able to click on a specific button inside List and have Main reroute from site/ to site/view{id}, similar to the way clicking on "search" in Main would route to site/search. I don't want to have View be inside Home or List, I want it to be a child of Main. How would I go about this? Passing a function that manually switches? Linking something somewhere? I'm relatively new to React and routers, but I didn't find anything from when I looked through the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it

1. To pass a function from main to child as props to retrieve id of clicked and load view data accordingly
2. Hence you are using react router you could add one more route

Look at below example link for more details

```
[CodePen]  https://codepen.io/dwarka/pen/PLEMWX
```

Comment: Also you would **not** want exact in this path. exact is for static paths which don't have children or parameters.

Comment: Actually using mobile not able format it but will do it soon

Comment: Put a tilde around the code. It's on mobile keyboards :)

Comment: @JoshuaUnderwood exact will still work as the id can change so it not only to static path you can check the codepen link given in answer

Comment: Thanks a bunch, seeing it in code was very helpful! I got it working now

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

You would need a route that looks something like this...

`<Route path="/view/:id" component={View} />`

and a Link like

`<Link to=/view/${thing.id}>Click me!</Link>`

Note the `:id` which denotes that there is a variable after the `view/`

Then in your **View** component you'll access the ID via `this.props.location`

If you'd rather pass the entire list item and not just the ID (because the data isn't accessible from the **View** component for whatever reason) you can also send the entire item like so

`<Link to={{ pathname: '/view', state: thing }}>Click Me!</Link>`

Then in the view component look at `this.props.location.state`

Also just a heads up, you don't need `exact` in a route unless you plan to have things after the *trailing* slash.

For example...

`route="/"` **Needs** exact

`route="/item"` Does **not** need exact

`route="/season"`  **Needs** exact cause it has subroutes (spring)

`route="/season/spring"` Does **not** need exact because it has no further subroutes

Comment: Thanks for including information on how to pass items and such! That was going to be my next thing to tackle, but now that's one less thing to worry about.